Filtering using Newtonsoft with multiple conditions in C#
I'm trying to extract values ​​from json using Newtonsoft, but I'm having some problems.
Below is the json snippet I use:
{
    "result": {
        "areas": [
            {
                "area": 1,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "name1",
                        "numbers": [
                            2,
                            2,
                            2,
                            1
                        ],
                        "value": 0.3
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "name2",
                        "numbers": [
                            0,
                            1,
                            0,
                            1
                        ],
                        "value": 0.6
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "name3",
                        "numbers": [
                            -2,
                            3,
                            1,
                            1
                        ],
                        "value": 0.5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "area": 2,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "name4",
                        "numbers": [
                            1,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4
                        ],
                        "value": 0.7
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

My task is to first filter by area (I need data only from area 1) and then select those items that meet the conditions for numbers:

1st number = 2 or = -2,
2nd number > 1,
3rd number > 0,
4th number = 1,

and then calculate the average value for these selected items.
In this case, I want to select items 1 and 3, i.e. to get an average of 0.4.
I first tried to do it in one filter with multiple conditions:
IEnumerable<JToken> numbers = jo.SelectTokens("$...items[?( (@.numbers[0] == 2 || @.numbers[0] == -2 ) && @.numbers[1] > 1 && @.numbers[2] > 0 && @.numbers[3] == 1)].value");

I got an error in this case because I can't use additional brackets in the query, and I don't know how else to check all the conditions.
Then I wrote each query separately and connected them using the Intersect() function:
IEnumerable<JToken> numbers0 = jo.SelectTokens("$...items[?(@.numbers[0] == 2 || @.numbers[0] == -2)]");
IEnumerable<JToken> numbers1 = jo.SelectTokens("$...items[?(@.numbers[1] > 1)]");
IEnumerable<JToken> numbers2 = jo.SelectTokens("$...items[?(@.numbers[2] > 0)]");
IEnumerable<JToken> numbers3 = jo.SelectTokens("$...items[?(@.numbers[3] == 1)]");

IEnumerable<JToken> numbers = numbers0.Intersect(numbers1.Intersect(numbers2.Intersect(numbers3)));

In this case, however, I am not able to extract the value and the entire json fragment is returned to me.
In both cases, I am unable to include the area filtering condition, the returned token is empty:
IEnumerable<JToken> area = jo.SelectTokens("$..areas[?( @.area == 1)]");

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe this can be fixed somehow without changing the approach.
And if this is not possible, what technique do you recommend? I've read a bit about LINQ and will try that next if the current task is unsolvable, unless you think there's something even better.

Why not use a class to represent the object and wrok from there. so you won't have to write any thing complexe.

Indeed, why not use JObect.Deserialize<> ? You gain nothing by trying to search array items over and over. You pay the cost of deserialization whether it's to JToken or objects, so why not produce something that's easy to query?

^^ That's what I suggested in Staging. OP said they want to give that a try and come back tomorrow.

Question boils down to 6 point : Witch part are you blocked on.
1/. "I'm trying to extract values ​​from json using Newtonsoft".
2/. How to generate class from Json.
3/. "filter by area 1"
4/. Valid item based on Numbers indexes and value.
5/. Use it to validation to get Item 1 and 3.
6/. Average the value.

You are correct that SelectTokens() does not support parenthesized combinations of AND and OR, see How can I create a JSONPath filter expression containing both AND and OR operators? for confirmation.  Thus the three possible workarounds from this answer for filtering the "$...items[*]" items should work for you as well.  Once you have filtered the items as required, you can append a .Select(i => i["value"]) to your query to select the value you need.
Specifically, you have the following three ways to work around Json.NET's limitation and select the values you need:

You can rely on Json.NET's undocumented behavior that A && B || C means A && (B || C):
var values = jo.SelectTokens("$...items[?(@.numbers[1] > 1 && @.numbers[2] > 0 && @.numbers[3] == 1 && @.numbers[0] == 2 || @.numbers[0] == -2)].value");

No added Select() is required with this approach.

You can use Intersect() as you are doing now, with an added Select():
var items0 = jo.SelectTokens("$...items[?(@.numbers[0] == 2 || @.numbers[0] == -2)]");
var items1 = jo.SelectTokens("$...items[?(@.numbers[1] > 1 && @.numbers[2] > 0 && @.numbers[3] == 1)]");

var values = items0.Intersect(items1).Select(i => i["value"]);


You could use LINQ to filter your items instead of JSONPath, with the added select:
var values = 
    from i in jo.SelectTokens("$...items[*]")
    let numbers = i["numbers"]
    where ((double?)numbers?[0] == 2 || (double?)numbers?[0] == -2) 
        && (double?)numbers?[1] > 1 
        && (double?)numbers?[2] > 0 
        && (double?)numbers?[3] == 1
    select i["value"];

This approach is, in my opinion, the most readable.


Once you have your values, you can average them by casting each selected JToken to a double? like so
var average = values.Average(v => (double?)v);

Demo fiddle showing all three approaches here.

I will try to solve this sentence by sentence with minimal coding.
1/. "I'm trying to extract values ​​from json using Newtonsoft"
-> https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm
2/. How to generate class from Json
https://app.quicktype.io

After those step: the code boils down to : live demo
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public static void Main()
{
  var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SoNumbers>(GetJson());
}

public static string GetJson()  {return "inputstring"; }

public partial class SoNumbers
{
  [JsonProperty("result")]
  public Result Result { get; set; }
}

public partial class Result
{
  [JsonProperty("areas")]
  public List<Area> Areas { get; set; }
}

public partial class Area
{
  [JsonProperty("area")]
  public long Id { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("items")]
  public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public partial class Item
{
  [JsonProperty("name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("numbers")]
  public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("value")]
  public double Value { get; set; }
}


3/. "filter by area 1"
result.Result.Areas.Where(x=> x.Id == 1)
4/. Valid item based on Numbers indexes and value.
static bool IsItemValid(Item item)
{
    return 
        (item.Numbers[0] == 2 || item.Numbers[0] == -2) 
      && item.Numbers[1] > 1
      && item.Numbers[2] > 0
      && item.Numbers[3] == 1;
}

5/. Use it to validation to get Item 1 and 3.
var validItems = area.Items.Where(IsItemValid);
6/. Average the value.
var avg = validItems.Average(x=> x.Value);

final result : livedemo
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SoNumbers>(GetJson());
var area1 = result.Result.Areas.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == 1);
var validItems = area1.Items.Where(IsItemValid);
var avg = validItems.Average(x=> x.Value);

Console.WriteLine($"Area n°{area1.Id}, ItemSelected = [{string.join(",",validItems.Select(x=> x.Name))}] Average = {avg};");


